# How to configure LDAP authentication module instance in OpenAM

Tags: authentication, ldap, single-sign-on, openam

I am trying to protect a Java servlet with OpenAM + J2EE tomcat agent. I got this part working by using embedded OpenDJ of OpenAM.

Now I am trying to authenticate against a LDAP server, so I added a LDAP module instance for OpenAM, but I get "User has no profile in this organization" when I am trying use uid/password of an user from that LDAP store.

I checked OpenAM administration guide on this the description is rather brief. I am wondering if it is even possible to do this without using the data store configured for OpenAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login process in OpenAM is made of two stages:

- Verifying credentials based on the authentication chain and individual authentication module configurations
- User profile lookup

By configuring the LDAP authentication module you took care of the authentication part, however the profile lookup fails as you haven't configured the user data store (see data stores tab). Having a configured data store allows you to potentially expose additional user details across your deployment (e.g. include user attributes in SAML assertions or map them to HTTP headers with the agent), so in most of the scenarios having a data store configured is necessary.

In case you still don't want to configure a data store, then you can prevent the user profile lookup failure by going to Access Control -> <realm> -> Authentication -> All Core Settings -> User Profile Mode and set it to Ignore.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for your help, Peter.

Comment: After I turned off user profile checking I was able to authenticate against the LDAP server through OpenAM.

Now here is the following-up problem: how do I verify against the user's group membership after a successful authentication? Say the LDAP store I am authenticating against has 1 million users, and I only want to grant users belongs to a specific group with the resource I am protecting, after they have been authenticated.

Without configured data store in OpenAM, is this kind of Authorization possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to authentication but it's related to authorization ... you have to configure appropriate policies ... see OpenAM docs.

Agents will enforce authorization, OpenAM determines if the user has the permission to access a protected resource.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for your explanation. I configured a J2EE policy and edited the "subject" field. I found OpenAM actually retrieved the group information (OU=mygroup...) from my LDAP directory. So everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

As Bernhard has indicated authentication is only part of the process of granting access to a user. He is referring to using a Policy to control access.

Another method is to check if the authenticated user is a member of the desired group programmatically. This can be useful when you want access control over resources that OpenAM doesn't know about (e.g. specific data).

For example, lets say that you want different groups to have access to different rows in a table in a database. You can retrieve the group information associated with the user and add that to your database query, thus restricting the data returned.

I'm sure that you could do this with OpenAM as well using custom modules to allow the policy to use information in the database as resource, but I've found it is much simpler to perform this fine grained access control in your code, and is in all likelihood significantly faster.